# mysql_fetch_array() works but mysql_fetch_object() doesn't

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which works:

```
$date1 = mysql_query("SELECT date1 FROM Users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
    or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($date1)){
    $lastViewedDate = $row[0];
}
```

But when I try to use mysql_fetch_object I get an Internal Server Error 500.

```
$date1 = mysql_query("SELECT date1 FROM Users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
    or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($date1)){
    $lastViewedDate = $row["date1"];
}
```

I would prefer to use the objects in the future but I don't understand why they aren't working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Inserting user data directly into your query is a very bad idea. Always use SQL placeholders as supported by `mysqli` or PDO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With fetch_object the syntax is :

```
$row->date1
```

with fetch_assoc the syntax is:

```
$row["date1"]
```

Also please.. for everything that is holy.. Turn E_NOTICE error messaging and display_errors on

Comment: Thanks for the info.  As a PHP noob I didn't even know about the E_NOTICE errors.  I looked it up and it looks like I just need to call this at the beginning of the script. error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);  Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @FuegoFingers: yes that call will help. It's even better to put in your php.ini, because certain errors may already get triggered, before you get a chance to call that function.

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing your object correctly it would be like this:

```
$date1 = mysql_query("SELECT date1 FROM Users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
    or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($date1)){
    $lastViewedDate = $row->date1;
}
```

Note the use of the object property accessor `->`

Comment: Probably because it continues to *promote* a SQL injection vulnerability .. would be my guess. The other answers simply omit showing/talking about it and thus don't "promote" such code, even if they don't "discourage" it either.

Comment: I felt the question was really more about accessing the properties of the object rather than the database access aspect. Thus, I just copied OP's code as is with single change made. Comments on the question had already made the typical "don't use mysql-*" suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$lastViewedDate = $row["date1"];
```

That's not how you access an object's variables; try this:

```
$lastViewedDate = $row->date1;
```